# Upload photos from Iphone photo gallery

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I'm just going to learn Objective-C, because I want to build an app that uploads all my media in the gallery on Iphone, to an FTP-server every midnight.

However, because the photo library may contain personal images, I read that the only way to access it is via user interaction. Is this really true? Can't just build a app that automatic every midnight takes all the media in my gallery and just simply upload it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **TRUE** the user is required to give there consent before uploading, this is because there maybe images that they don't want uploading. So yes you can build an app that does what you want but this kind of app will never make it into the app store. As I don't work for Apple I am only taking a guess at some of the things they would reject you for, here is a small list :

> **17.1** - Apps cannot transmit data about a user without obtaining the user's prior permission and providing the user with access to information about how and where the data will be used
>
> **22.4** - Apps that enable illegal file sharing will be rejected

I'd probably say with a good legal spin they could reject you for

> **17.4** -Apps that collect, transmit, or have the capability to share personal information (e.g. name, address, email, location, photos, videos, drawings, the ability to chat, other personal data, or persistent identifiers used in combination with any of the above) from a minor must comply with applicable children's privacy statutes, and must include a privacy policy

(Please note like I say I don't work for Apple so I can only speculate what they would reject it for but it can't be done)

Comment: So I CAN build this kind of app that allows me to upload media from my gallery in the "background" without user interaction? BUt I CAN'T add this app at appstore? Am I right?

Comment: Yes because if you weren't submitting it to the app store you can do whatever the hell you want. But you are getting into the realms of developing for Jail broken devices now. My answer is purely for if you wanted to submit to the app store. So if you want it in the app store then that is a huge **NO** you can't

Comment: But I can Install my app on my NOT jailbroken Iphone? I can only link to my .IPA-file, and then access it via my Iphone to download it?

Comment: Yeah that is fine you can do whatever you want on a device before it is submitted to the App store. The issue will be when you submit it and it is in the Apple review process they will reject it for breaching the Review guidelines. So the only way you will be able to get your app out there in the public domain is to have it work on Jailbroken devices because you will not get it into the app store.

Comment: The way it works is you code your app to do what you want it to do then you submit it to be reviewed so it will be in the Apple App Store and if it breaches one of the review guidelines they will reject your app if it doesn't they will allow it into the App Store.

Comment: I don't want it on appstore. I just only want it to my phones at home. Once again, I can download&install this kind of app, by linking to my .IPA-file that is located on my private server, on my Iphone device that is NOT jailbroken?

Comment: Well you can do whatever you want in that case. But you didn't provide that information so the answer given was based on the assumption that you were going through the app store. You need to provide us with all the information because answer will be hugely different based on that bit of information. Please update your question

Comment: I didn't get it.. Could I write an app that upload all my media inside the gallery, with the UIImagePickerController, without user interaction? I want it like an hidden service in the background.

Comment: What don't you get? If you are making an app for the app store then **NO** you can't do it. If you are making it for jailbroken devices or an app that isn't going into the app store then more than likely yes you can do it but you haven't told us which you want in your question so we assume it is for the app store.

Comment: It is an app that isn't going int o the app store. It's also isn't for an jailbroken device. I will only make a link to my .IPA-file. But does the UIIMagePickerController ALLOW me to ge the images from the library without user interaction?

Comment: See this is why you need to add it to your question because you will have completely different answer based on it not going into the app store. There will be a private API somewhere that will interact with a UIImagePickerController in the background but there is no public API, you'll have to go searching the web for the private API which will be hard since they are very rarely if at all documented.